# Index out of range while accessing index of the next iteration in loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

There are several image files in a directory on which I need to iterate through, where need to access the next iteration value in the current iteration.

```
img_files_list = os.listdir(/path/to/directory)
new_list = []
for index, img in enumerate(img_files_list):
    if img in new_list:
        continue
    new_list.extend([img, img_files_list[index + 1], img_files_list[index + 2]])
    print(img)
    print(img_files_list[index + 1])
    print(img_files_list[index + 2])
```

I need to iterate over all the items of the **img_files_list** but when reached at the end of the loop need to properly come out of loop without **index out of range exception**. Anyone, please point out where do I missed the logic.

Comment: `index + 1` and `index + 2` cause a problem for last 2 items. For example, if your list's size is 10, then indexes will be **0,2,...,9**. When the index is 8 and 9, you are trying to execute `img_files_list[10]` and `img_files_list[11]`. So the index is out of range.

Comment: Why do you need index+2? Because cause of error is it. For ex., if you have 2 element in list, index values will be 0, 1. And for first element, index+1 is 1. But index+2 is 2 and it is out of range.

Comment: You will add only one if line after for line.  if index < (len(img_files_list) - 2) :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems more like Code Review than Stack Overflow.

When you reach the last item in your `for image, img in enumerate(img_files_list)` line, there is no item after the last one. This is what causes an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

There are a few ways to approach this:

1. As Sruthi V. wrote, include a condition:

   ```
   print(img_files_list[i])
   if i + 1 < len(img_files_list):
       print(img_files_list[i + 1])
   if i + 2 < len(img_files_list):
       print(img_files_list[i + 2])
   ```
2. Include a `try... except`:

   ```
   try:
       print(img_files_list[i])
       print(img_files_list[i + 1])
       print(img_files_list[i + 2])
   except IndexOutOfRangeException:
       pass
   ```
3. Limit the range of your loop:

   ```
   i_img = list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']))
   for i, img in i_img [:len(i_img ) - 2]:
       print(img)
       print(i_img[i + 1])
       print(i_img[i + 2])
   ```

Note that you have no reason to use `enumerate` — you're just using it to get indices. You also don't need your `if img in new_list` — you're just using it to skip the next two. You can make this more elegant and solve your problem using range (a modified solution 3).

```
imgs = os.listdir('/path/to/directory')
triplets = []
for i in range(0, len(imgs) - 2, 3):
    triplet = [imgs[i], imgs[i + 1], imgs[i + 2]]
    triplets.extend(triplet)
    print('\n'.join(triplet))
```

N.B. I'm not sure what you're even trying to do. Even your `if img in new_list` might be a mistake since it just skips the last 1-2 final items. And if that were gone, all you would be doing is making a copy of this list and printing its contents. In which case I would suggest:

```
imgs = os.listdir('/path/to/directory')
print('\n'.join(imgs))
```

But if you clarify what you're trying to do, I can edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment to your question:

> `index + 1` and `index + 2` cause a problem for last 2 items. For
>   example, if your list's size is 10, then indexes will be 0,2,...,9.
>   When the index is 8 and 9, you are trying to execute
>   `img_files_list[10]` and `img_files_list[11]`. So the index is out of
>   range.

I assume that you want to access images as 3-item list, then I suggest you a little bit different way. I will use an integer array instead of images for a better understanding.

```
img_files_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
new_list = []  
n = 3
for i in range(0, len(img_files_list), n): # Respectively, i is 0,3,6,9,...
    temp = img_files_list[i:i+n]
    print(temp)
    new_list.extend(temp)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]
```